# Search a text inside .class files in zip file as well

Tags: java

I'm using IntelliJ and eclipse as well.

Assume i want to search for a text example - XML_TYPE in all the class files which has been residing inside the jar files.

Usually we will be adding the dependency jar files to the class path.

Now i want to lookup or search for a particular text in all the class files inside the jar files as well.

Any plugin or any other way to do it quickly?

Thanks.

Comment: you want to search for a text in a byte code?

Comment: I guess that is the wrong approach. What is `XML_TYPE` supposed to be? An Enum-Value? A string constant? You could try to write it somewhere in code and use IDE's "Goto Source" or "Goto Definition" - whatever it is in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

install jadclipse tool in eclipse using install new software option. then go to project explorer and  press ctrl+h and search content in .class files.
using  jadclipse tool you are able to see .class files codes.

Comment: hi vikash, do you know how to do the same in intelliJ